# async-await status resolved but ajax not complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await

I am trying to wait on a `getJson` call and process the data that comes back.  I've seen lots of answers and have tried using `$.ajax`'s `async: false` (doesn't work because the query is cross domain), callbacks, and the `.done` part of a basic `$.ajax` call. Now I'm trying async-await. My code looks like this:

```js
var ths = getTrailheads(turl);
console.log("trailheads promise");
console.log(ths);
ths.then(function(data) {
  addTrailheadsToMap(data);
});

async function getTrailheads(turl) {
  var result = await $.ajax({
    url: turl,
    datatype: 'json'
  });

  return result;
}
```

It works sometimes, if the ajax call comes back fast enough, but mostly, the console log shows:

[image: promise object]

This shows the promise with `status` set to `Resolved`. The promise object is there, but the object status shows `Processing`.

This is a common case, but the common answers don't seem to be working for me so any help would be appreciated.

update:

```js
  preGetTrailheads(turl);
}
async function preGetTrailheads(turl) {
  var ths = await getTrailheads(turl);
  console.log("trailheads promise");
  console.log(ths);
  addTrailheadsToMap(ths);

}
async function getTrailheads(turl) {
  var result = await $.ajax({
    url: turl,
    datatype: 'json'
  });

  return result;
}
```

Now I get the object back instead of a promise, but the object is still "Processing" and then fails when I try to use it.
[object dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVLSu.png)

Update 2:
I'm sure both of you guys are right, and the way you describe is how you do it.  I have a codepen here https://codepen.io/mckee80/pen/KJBbvz .  It works most of the time.  It only seems to fail the first time you run it (also, the output goes to the browser log when it is successful).  I just need to figure out why it is happening on my app.  Strangely, it works for a given dataset if I reload the page.

Comment: `var ths = getTrailheads(turl);` should be `var ths = await getTrailheads(turl);`. You need to await the result of your async call

Comment: Thanks.  But when I do that, I get back the object, but the status is still "processing"

Comment: You need to go async all the way or at some point use the promise pattern to handle the callbacks when your async function completes

Comment: In your update you are logging the result of the function (a promise) before you have waited for `then`. Move your `console.log` call inside of the `then` block

Comment: Thanks.  In the update, it doesn't return a promise, it returns the object (so it isn't thenable).

Comment: "*but the object is still `"Processing"`*" - well that's just the value that you get from the API. Your promise syntax is fine, but it seems you're not using the API correctly or the server-side code is broken.

Comment: I think you're right.  It must be a problem on the other side.  It is just a public datastore, so I'll have to work around it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async/await inside `getTrailheads` properly, but the code calling it also needs to use async/await or otherwise handle promises. Assuming that code can be `async` you probably just need to add `await` before the call:

`var ths = await getTrailheads(turl);`

async/await is more or less syntactic sugar on top of promises, which is why not awaiting the result of `getTrailheads` returns a promise. You could also use `getTrailheads(turl).then(ths => {...})` if that works better.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the question with my current situation.  I get the object back instead of the promise, but it is still not complete when I get it.

Comment: Marked as accepted since this is the right way to do it.  Ultimately, it is some sporadic failures on the server end that tripped me up.  Thanks for the help!